# SQL connection string to AG Listener from Always ON

Tags: sql, asp-classic, connection-string

We're trying to connect to SQL / Always on from CLASSIC ASP, but we have a problem:

> Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Our connection string:

```
Server=tcp:LISTENERNAME,1433;Database=DATABASENAME;Uid=USERNAME;Pwd=PASSWORD;
```

However, our old (OLEDB) connection string (without Always ON), works just fine:

Old connection string:

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=IP address,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Database=DATABASENAME;Uid=USERNAME;Pwd=PASSWORD;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I think the clue's in the error message - you need to specify your [driver or at least a provider name](http://www.connectionstrings.com/).

Comment: ... of course, instead of LISTENERNAME... we put real name as defined at our SQL server AG listner name ... but without success.

Comment: Ah! No - just me getting the wrong end of the stick. Ignore my comment.

Comment: Presumably you have created a DSN http://www.devasp.com/samples/dsn_sql.asp